# Copy Paste Issue from ssms 2012 to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I am facing issue in copying and pasting data from ssms 2012 to excel for particular.

While copy paste there are certain lines that gets break into excel.

for example: this below line gets split multiple columns in excel

```
(310) 277 4657 Lori Parkes called adv not auth on the account, provided general info re LEASE EXTENSION:  
  1 2 mo. as courtesy. 4 more with Prod# or POD. Max 6 mo
  Same mo pymt, credit reporting remains active. Prorated miles.  Warranty &amp; addtl prod. not extended. 
  Adv must keep reg/ins valid (CA must renew for an entire year)
```

How to keep this data in one column when pasting to excel?

I tried using `REPLACE([CRM Note], CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ', ') as CRM` and `REPLACE([CRM Note],char(10), ''), char(13), '')` but this is not working.

Comment: I suggest you post two examples of what you're trying to achieve here, one where it works and another one where it doesn't, please keep your question clear and minimal, read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example it helps.
As a new user, I encourage you to read through the help (https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: why not just you use a connection external from excel and after to configure your sql connection?

Answer (score 2):

Excel uses tabs to break text into columns when pasting, so you need to have your copied data separated by tab CHR(9), anyway, you can always use `Data -> Text to Columns` feature in excel and select you separator char after selecting the cells you want to break.

**Edit 1**
I thought you want to break the data into columns, but you want to keep `CRM` in one column if it's getting broken to multiple columns then it must have TABs CHR(9) and you need to do `REPLACE([CRM Note], CHAR(9), ', ') as CRM`.